# Overwrite previous checkbox value on button click

Tags: c#, html, sql, .net, checkbox

I am saving a checkbox value using 'Yes' & 'No' and my problem is I have a button click that would allow the user to change the value.

So my logic is, if button is clicked the checkbox value that is no would change to yes.

Here is what I have to save the information originally:

```
     public void StoredProcedure()
    {
        string privateItem = Private.Checked ? "Y" : "N";

        connection.connection1();
        if (connection.con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            connection.con.Open();
        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SaveImage", connection.con))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@privatecheck", SqlDbType.Char).Value = privateItem;

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }
        connection.con.Close();
    }
```

Basically I have a stored procedure in my database that will save my information.

Now what I was thinking to update one value is to basically do the same thing but it resulted in an error for me.

Any help on how to overwrite a previously saved checkbox value would be extremely helpful!

Thanks

Comment: An error, please elaborate? How is Char Data Type getting assigned a bool value?

Comment: Please show/tell the error message and the code that generated the error

Comment: Are you looking to modified the checkbox value on the checkbox control or the database value?

Comment: Hello @Pseudonym, I was looking to modify the checkbox value in the database.

Comment: You're setting `privateItem` as a string, but then using `Private.Checked` as the value on the parameter... looks like a mistake

Comment: @freefaller, thanks yeah I made that correction. Mistyped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not entirely clear on what you are asking for so my answer gives two possible solutions:

If you are looking to modify whether or not the control itself is checked or not checked here is a piece of sample code from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.checkbox.checked%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private void AdjustMyCheckBoxProperties()
 {
    // Change the ThreeState and CheckAlign properties on every other click. 
    if (!checkBox1.ThreeState)
    {
       checkBox1.ThreeState = true;
       checkBox1.CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleRight;
    }
    else
    {
       checkBox1.ThreeState = false;
       checkBox1.CheckAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleLeft;
    }

    // Concatenate the property values together on three lines.
    label1.Text = "ThreeState: " + checkBox1.ThreeState.ToString() + "\n" +
                  "Checked: " + checkBox1.Checked.ToString() + "\n" +
                  "CheckState: " + checkBox1.CheckState.ToString(); 
 }
```

If instead you are looking to modify a column in a table, an UPDATE SQL statement will do that for here, [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386927%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) has a nice walkthrough on how to use LINQ and SQL to achieve this which I would recommend reading.

However I see you are using `SqlCommand` so here is the example code on how to perform an update command (again) from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executenonquery%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
private static void CreateCommand(string queryString,
    string connectionString)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(
               connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
        command.Connection.Open();
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

All of the above pieces should help you generate a solution.